# VB.Net - Sending out mail as html and plaintext

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, email, smtp

I have a mail function 'Sendmail' in my VB app, as so...

```
 Public Function Sendmail(ByVal mailrecipient As String, ByVal mailsubject As String, ByVal mailbody As String)
        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New _
        Net.NetworkCredential(internal_mail_server_username, internal_mail_server_password)
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = internal_mail_server
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress(internal_email_sender)
            mail.To.Add(mailrecipient)
            mail.Subject = mailsubject
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            mail.Body = mailbody
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MessageBox.Show("Mail successfully sent to " & mailrecipient)
            Return "Success"

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Function
```

This works great, passing the recipient, subject and body to it sends HTML mail out... fantastic.

What I need to is include with that email a plain text version with the mail that goes out.

Is there a simple way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use alterativeViews

```
'first create the Plain Text part
Dim plainView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Plain_Text)
'then  create the Html part
Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(HTML_Text)
mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView)
mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
```

Obviously you need to pass both the PLain_Text and HTML_Text as parameters to the routine.

Comment: Do i keep the 'mail.IsBodyHtml = True' and 'mail.Body = mailbody' bits?

Comment: IsBOdyHTML should set the default, .body u don't need though if I remember rightly